# Using Multiple JQuery-ui datepickers on same page with multiple languages (English, Japanese)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using 2 datepickers on the same page with 2 languages(English, Japanese). The first time when I select the date in both date datepicker then it's working properly but second, the third time I select the date from Japanese and then I try to click & select date from English datepicker it shows Japanese characters for weekdays & month. It should show appropriate fonts for each language datepickers. Please help me to find out solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code sample and screenshots of the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your code, we may be better able to help.

But according to the docs at https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ you can specify the `locale` / `language` per picker in the setup parameters.

e.g.

```
$( selector ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

Comment: thanks, @Mike we are using this but the issue is different when we click Japanese calendar & then go back to English to select dates at that time it shows Japanese characters on the English calendar so it creates conflicts.